# gitosis how to deny read access to everyone but one user who can also write

Tags: git

I'm struggling to get gitosis deny read access to a repository. Basically I want only one user to have read and write access to it. At the moment everyone can clone the tree and this is precisely what I don't want. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got this sort of question it helps to post your configuration.  Gitosis doesn't grant any access to a repository other than what you've explicitly configured.  A really simple `gitosis.conf` might look like this:

```
[group gitosis-admin]
members = lars
writable = gitosis-admin

[group myproject]
members = lars
writable = myproject
```

This allows someone identified as "lars" read/write access to the
"admin" and "myproject" repositories, and grants no access to anyone
else.  If you've got something like this and it's not working as you expect, add the following:

```
[gitosis]
loglevel = DEBUG
```

This will cause gitosis to log verbosely when you interact with it.  Post your `gitosis.conf` and the output of the `DEBUG` logging from Gitosis and we can probably give you a better answer.

Comment: What happened is I overlooked `daemon = yes` option in my gitosis.conf. I've now removed it and deleted `git-daemon-export-ok` file and everything is working as I want it to. Cheers!